# Accidentally overwrote file instead of appending. Is there hope?

Tags: mac-osx, unix, osx-leopard

I accidentally did this:

```
command > ~/.bash_profile
```

Instead of

```
command >> ~/.bash_profile
```

I know, I'm an idiot. Is there a way to recover the old `.bash_profile` file?

Thanks a lot for your help

PS: The machine is a macbook pro with Leopard.

Comment: Lesson learned : ALWAYS , no matter what are you editing, do a backup first

Comment: It's not about backing up data, it was a typo on the command

Comment: Thats a secondary thing... you edited bash_profile anyway

Answer (score 3):

Unless you had Time Machine or some other backup of the file, it's gone.

If that was the original .bash_profile, according to [this page](http://hintsforums.macworld.com/archive/index.php/t-9311.html), the default setup for users is stored in `/System/Library/User Template/English.lproj`, you should be able to get another copy of the original from there.  Or just create a new user and take theirs.

Answer (score 2):

I've just got the same accident. This is how I could recover some lost data in my bash_profile. Assume you are **still in the terminal** where you've just run the bad command:

```
$ echo 'something' > ~/.bash_profile
```

For PATH and ENV variables, use this command:

```
$printenv
```

For aliases, use this command and copy the ouput:

```
$alias
```

For functions, use this command to list all the function names:

```
$compgen -A function
```

And use this command to show the content of a function name:

```
$type function_name
```

Hope this helps some other people :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but unlikely. The effort involved in recovering it will most likely be harder than simply rewriting it or recovering it from a backup.